# Is it possible to create a UDP/TCP reverse gaming tunnel?

Tags: linux, networking, tunnel, ubuntu-22.04, reverse-tunnel

For reference, I don't have much experience in the routing/networking world. I have a gaming server hosted on my desktop running in Linux Ubuntu headless 22.04. it's running on a local IP something like 192.169.1.185. I want to expose the port 25567, but I do not have access to the main router since I live in an apartment. The ethernet comes out of the wall. I can grab the public IP of the main router using a simple find-my-IP website, but other than that I am at a loss. It is possible to use a reverse tunneling software for UDP/TCP ports such as [reverse-tunnel rtun](https://github.com/snsinfu/reverse-tunnel)? Is anyone able to explain how this works? Also, I don't have access to a VPN, unfortunately.

Comment: [`pwnat`](http://samy.pl/pwnat/) or [`chownat`](http://samy.pl/chownat/) maybe, but I haven't tested them. I'm posting the links because there is "how does it work?" in each document.